# Увеличить значение на 1 JS

Tags: javascript

Имеется следующее:

```
var counters = {'private': 0, 'public': 0, 'chat': 0 };
var increment = true;
var type = 'private';

counters[type] = (increment) ? counters[type]++ : counters[type]--;
console.log(counters);
```

Консоль выдает по нулям, почему так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что есть два типа инкремента/декремента:

- i++ - вернуть значение и увеличить значение
- ++i - увеличить значение и вернуть значение

Поэтому сначала возвращается значение (ноль), а затем увеличивается/уменьшается (уже непонятно что).
И на всякий еще скажу, что консоль выдает для объекта те значения, которые в нем были в момент открытия этого объекта. Поэтому там иногда можно встретить слишком свежие данные.